# Another term for "instant feedback"?

Tags: phrase-requests, vocabulary, synonyms

I'm looking for another term for "instant feedback". Something perhaps similar to how common the phrase "instant gratification" is used to mean instant results from an action.

For context, I'm trying to describe the way a video game's camera will capture and immediately display a player's movements on screen so they can react/correct their movements.

Comment: You can say it's *highly responsive*, or *has a low response time*, but frankly, there is nothing wrong with *instant feedback*. In fact *instant* is not as wishy-washy as *high/low*. Why are you looking for another term?

Comment: It's mostly trying to find a wording that flows nicely. i.e. As you put it "the system is highly responsive" instead of "the system provides instant feedback". I felt there was another phrasing just on the tip of my tongue but couldn't think of it. If nothing better I'd consider responsive an answer.

Comment: In similar contexts, the standard or customary adverb is "dynamic".

Comment: "Immediate real-time response," maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something responsive / very responsive

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/responsive

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/responsive

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/responsive

Comment: This is the term I ended up going with, though some of the other answers aren't bad either.

Comment: @fromcanada credits to Reg whose comment I missed.

Answer (score 0):

Try *reactive*.

It is used in the area of realtime systems to refer to the need to accept, process, and respond/react to many inputs in real time (i.e., fast).

Answer (score 0):

I like: ***instantaneous feedback***

> *“The user receives instantaneous feedback to gestures in this game.”*– or – *“The game reacts instantly to user inputs.”*

(Caution: the term *“real-time”* is tricky in the realm of computer programming.  In the most literal sense there is no such thing as real-time reproduction, so technical people may balk – not unlike how some people wince at the inaccurate use/overstatement of the word *“infinite”*.)

Answer (score 0):

You could say it has *[low latency](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_latency)*.

Answer (score 0):

To steal a term from sociology - **Reflexivity**

This means a feedback loop of cause and effect.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexivity_(social_theory)